# Add elements to HashMap<String, List> - .containsKey() always returns false

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have `List<HashMap>` of mail addressess, along with users ids (each entry in list looks like: `id`: `123`,  `mail`: `"john@doe.com"`).

I want to make a `HashMap` in which every key is a domain name of e-mail address, and value is list of e-mails from that domain:

```
"foo.com":
  [1]
      id: 123,
      mail: a@foo.com
  [2]
      id: 345
      mail: b@foo.com
"bar.com":
  [1]
      id: 787,
      mail: a@bar.com
  [2]
      id: 456
      mail: b@bar.com
```

To achieve that, I do what's below. Problem is, when I try to add new list entry to list existing on `domain` entry, java adds new record to `sortedAddresses` instead of using present one. My prediction is `containsKey()` method always returns false.

```
HashMap<String, List> sortedAddresses = new HashMap<String, List>();

        for(HashMap<String, String> r : this.lightUsersList){

            String mail = r.get("email");
            Integer uid = Integer.parseInt(r.get("id"));


            try{
                String[] mailSplit = mail.split("@");
                String domain = mailSplit[1];

                //if domain key doesn't exist, add it to hashmap
                if(!sortedAddresses.containsKey(domain)){
                    List<HashMap> domainAddr = new ArrayList<HashMap>();
                    sortedAddresses.put(domain, domainAddr);
                }

                List<HashMap> domainAddr = sortedAddresses.get(domain);
                sortedAddresses.remove(domain);
                domainAddr.add(r);
                sortedAddresses.put(domain, domainAddr);

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                //to be implemented
                System.out.println("Nie udalo sie dodac adresu " + mail + " do tablicy domenowej (" + e.getMessage() + ")");
            }



                //displaying hashmap summary (source from another SO thread)
                Iterator it = sortedAddresses.entrySet().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
                    System.out.println(pairs.getKey() + " = " + sortedAddresses.get(pairs.getKey()).size());
                    it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
                } 
        }
```

Output I get:

```
foo = 1
bar = 1
foo = 1
bar = 1
```

Should be:

```
foo = 2
bar = 2
```

Comment: If you can think that far why don't you just debug it step by step?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it seems that I see where I made a mistake. Of course `Iterator` part should be after `for` loop. My bad. Hate mondays.